# How to send custom notifications using twilio whatsapp without registering receiver's number?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-node

I have followed the following steps from https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/quickstart/node which works great with my the number I have registered with custom messages.
Now I changed the number with another WhatsApp number I had but it's not sending messages to that. How do I send without registering?
Please note that I have a trial account.

```
// This works
const whatsappMessage = await textTransport.messages
      .create({
        from: 'whatsapp:+14155238886',
        body: 'Hello there!',
        to: 'whatsapp:+91888888888' // registered number to twilin
      });
```

```
// This doesnt work
const whatsappMessage = await textTransport.messages
      .create({
        from: 'whatsapp:+14155238886',
        body: 'Hello there!',
        to: 'whatsapp:+91999999999'  // not registered
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio API for WhatsApp allows you to test using our sandbox](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#twilio-sandbox-for-whatsapp). However, to send messages to your users without the sandbox restrictions you need to [request your own WhatsApp enabled number](https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp/request-access).

Answer (score -1):

To receive message to new number must send  `join [KEY-WORD]` from the new number to the WhatsApp number, as you do with the first number

Comment: I understand. The questions is how do I do that without joining the sandbox means without regesterin. I can't ask my customer to register, so that I can send whatsup notifications.

Comment: That is the same question i ask it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58650489/how-to-send-messages-using-twilio-whatsapp-without-sending-a-join-key-word-w/58651635#58651635

Comment: If you got a solution please tell me