# How to send messages using twilio whatsapp without sending a "join [KEY-WORD]" WhatsApp message

Tags: twilio

I want to send whatsapp messages to my WhatsApp recipients but WhatsApp recipients need to opt-in by sending a "join [KEY-WORD]" WhatsApp message to the phone number you choose in the Sandbox

I want to send message without need to send "join [KEY-WORD]" WhatsApp message

How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are using the sandbox, which is for testing only. To use whatsApp normally with your users you need to request access to the real API using this link https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp/request-access

Comment: Do i need to upgrade my account ?

Comment: Yes, I think you need to. Also you have to purchase a number and request access to the API using the link above.